# Trying to get process name from Exec= line in .desktop file. Error when running Exec= when its a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, .desktop

I've written this shell script to get the name of the process spawned from the exec line.

My issue is when I try it on Arduino IDE I get an error. I investigated and its exec line is another shell script.

I'm not sure if this is my issue but I've been trying to play around with it to make it load and I just cant seem to.

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

exe=$(grep '^Exec' "$1" | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%[a-zA-Z]*//')
type=$(file $exe | grep "Bourne-Again")

if [ -z "$type" ]; then
  echo Debug - its a shell script
  bash "$exe" &
else
  echo Debug - its not a shell script
  $exe &
fi
PID=$(echo $!)
process=$(ps --no-header -p $PID -o comm)
kill -SIGTERM $PID

echo $exe 
echo $process
```

The error

```
bash PycharmProjects/touch_mouser/TouchMouser/get_exe_and_process_name.sh "/usr/share/applications/arduino-arduinoide.desktop"

Debug - its a shell script
bash: "/home/lewis/builds/arduino/arduino-1.8.12/arduino": No such file or directory
PycharmProjects/touch_mouser/TouchMouser/get_exe_and_process_name.sh: line 15: kill: (27840) - No such process
"/home/lewis/builds/arduino/arduino-1.8.12/arduino" ====
```

But if I run this is the terminal it works fine.

```
bash "/home/lewis/builds/arduino/arduino-1.8.12/arduino"
```

Any one know why or shed any light on it?

Comment: What is the exact output of your `grep '^Exec'...` command? I suspect it is returning `"script.sh"` and not `script.sh`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with terdon. You could add `echo bash "$exe"` before the actual bash line `bash "$exe" &` to see what's happening there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `exe` variable has the name of the script quoted. So, if the script is `foo.sh`, then `$exe` is actually `"foo.sh"` and not `foo.sh`. Therefore, you are telling bash to find a file whose name includes those quotes. To illustrate, here's an artificial example:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "It ran!"
```

Now, set a variable to the script's name quoted:

```
$ exe='"foo.sh"'
$ echo "$exe"
"foo.sh"
```

And try to run it:

```
$ bash "$exe"
bash: "foo.sh": No such file or directory
```

And the same thing but without putting the name of the scripts already quoted in the variable:

```
$ exe="foo.sh"
$ echo "$exe"
foo.sh
$ bash "$exe"
It ran!
```

So, just remove the quotes and you should be set:

```
exe=$(grep '^Exec' "$1" | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//; s/%[a-zA-Z]*//; s/"//g')
```

Comment: You are a genius.